# How do I get members of a dynamically typed array in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, casting

I'm dynamically calling web services in my program using the WSProxy class [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/39138d08-aa08-4c0c-9a58-0eb81a672f54), and I need to parse the returned object to XML, or at least access the members inside the returned web service result.

For example, if I receive an Array of StateCodes, I need to do:

```
 public object RunService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, string jsonArgs)
    {

        WSDLRuntime.WsProxy wsp = new WSDLRuntime.WsProxy();

        // Convert JSON to C# object.
        JavaScriptSerializer jser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dict = jser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(jsonArgs);

        // uses mi.Invoke() from the WSProxy class, returns an object.
        var result = wsp.CallWebService(webServiceAsmxUrl, serviceName, methodName, dict);
```

I've tried various methods to get to array members, but I'm hitting a dead end.

```
        // THIS WON'T WORK.
        // "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'"
        var firstResult = result[0];

        // THIS WON'T WORK.
        // "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"
        foreach (var i in result)
        {

        }


return object

//At the end of the class, if I try to return the object for XML parsing, I'll get this: 
//System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type StateCodes[] may not be used in this context.
   //at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteTypedPrimitive(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean xsiType)
```

Since I won't know the type of the array which is returned beforehand, I can't do early binding. I'm using C# 3.5, which I've just started learning. I keep hearing "reflection" coming up, but the examples I've read don't seem to apply to this question.

If this question is confusing, it's because I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting it to IEnumerable

```
var list = result as IEnumerable;
if(list != null) 
{
   foreach (var i in list)
   {
       // Do stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try casting it to `IEnumerable`.

```
var goodResult = result as IEnumerable;

if (goodResult != null) // use it
```