# How do I return a dynamically typed object in my C# web service?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, types

I have a followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157191/how-do-i-get-members-of-a-dynamically-typed-array-in-c).

I'm writing a web service which dynamically calls other web services, using the WSProxy class found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/39138d08-aa08-4c0c-9a58-0eb81a672f54).

Using WSProxy returns an object with a dynamic type, depending on the web service method called. For example, if I'm calling a method that returns...

```
<StateCodes>
    <StateCode>
        <Code>AL</Code>
        <Name>Alabama</Name>
    </StateCode>
    <!-- and so on -->
</StateCodes>
```

then the object is of the type *StateCodes[]*.

If I'm calling a method that returns ...

```
<GetVehicleMakes>
    <VehicleMakes>
      <Vehicle_Make_Code>00</Vehicle_Make_Code>
      <Vehicle_Make_Description>Ford</Vehicle_Make_Description>
    </VehicleMakes>
    <VehicleMakes>
      <Vehicle_Make_Code>01</Vehicle_Make_Code>
      <Vehicle_Make_Description>Toyota</Vehicle_Make_Description>
    </VehicleMakes>
    <!-- and so on -->
</GetVehicleMakes>
```

then the object is of the type *GetVehicleMakes[]*.

I can't declare a class type beforehand because the class type of the returned object is determined by the web service method called, and the web service method is determined at runtime. There are dozens of methods with different return types on the local service I'm testing against. **I don't get to know the type of the returned object before runtime, because any method from any web service could be called.**

When I try to return the object straight up, like so:

```
[WebMethod]
public object RunService(string webServiceAsmxUrl, string serviceName, string methodName, string jsonArgs)
{

    WSDLRuntime.WsProxy wsp = new WSDLRuntime.WsProxy();

    // Convert JSON to C# object.
    JavaScriptSerializer jser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var dict = jser.Deserialize<Dictionary<string,object>>(jsonArgs);

    object result = wsp.CallWebService(webServiceAsmxUrl, serviceName, methodName, dict);

    // This line produces the error.
    return result;

}
```

I can insert a breakpoint at the **return result** line, and browse my **result** object. For example, when I call the StateCodes method, the result variable is the StateCodes[] array.

However, once **return result** runs, the XML parser won't have it.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The type StateCodes[] may not be used in this context.
```

I've searched for answers, and I see terms like, "reflection" and "serialization" coming up, but I am very new to C# and don't know if these are what I want or how they work.
I'm using C# 3.5.

Comment: What do you expect the caller of this service to do with this dynamic type that it knows nothing about?

Comment: I have no idea. I started learning C# about two weeks ago, and it's my first "real" (compiled) language. My theory is if I can insert a breakpoint into my code and inspect this object, there must be a way to get the XML parser to read it. After all, the WSProxy class somehow dynamically creates a new method from the WSDL at runtime.

Comment: To answer your question, I'm expecting the caller to turn this object into something that an XML parser can read.

Comment: @Jake: Then you don't want to return a dynamic object - you want to return XML. And, BTW, nobody will be able to do anything useful with that XML since they don't know ahead of time what it looks like.

Comment: Normally, at least the way I understand it, in .net you can return any variable of a known class type and the XML parser will turn it into <type>value</type>. My problem is I don't know how to turn this dynamic object into something that the XML parser can understand.

Comment: I suspect the OP just wants to serialize the `dynamic` instance into XML; the web service part is consequential; you should just be able to return XML. Anyway, what I am wondering, Jake: you say the data is `dynamic`, but you have a type: `StateCode[]`; that sounds contradicting. Could you please add the code that throws the exception? That will very likely clear things up.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is what I'm looking for. I've edited my question to include the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need to return the xml that is returned from the service call. You can't return the object directly because the top-level service (the one that has a return type of object) is not generated at runtime; it is defined when its wsdl is consumed.

Long story short, you should change the return type of your top-level WebMethod to be string and serialize `result` manually in order to do what you want. Then the client (who presumably knows what they expect to get back from the service that they are requesting via `webServiceAsmxUrl`, `serviceName`, and `methodName`) can deserialize the result themselves.

Comment: That's too bad; the whole point of my using Visual Studio's web services is to not have to serialize manually. I guess my approach isn't feasible to achieve this end. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Technically, you do and you don't have to serialize manually. The web service handles serializing the string as the return value (and puts on the soap header, etc), but you have to serialize your object to be the return string :-)